# How to make TOAD for MySql treat empty strings as null

Tags: mysql, null, toad

I am aware that MySql treats empty strings and nulls differently, unlike Oracle where they are the same.  And that's fine.  But what I am wondering is if it's possible to have TOAD for MySql turn empty strings into nulls.  Look at the image below.  `{null}` is my placeholder for null values so I can easily tell them apart.  While I am working in the data grids if I remove data I get empty strings.  If I remove data I want it to become `null` instead.  I can't seem to find a way to make this happen.  I always have to run a script to set the data to `null`.  Does anyone know if it's possible to my this happen in TOAD so I don't have to keep running scripts to set my nulls?  (version 7.0.0.2038). If it's not possible does anyone know of an application that does?

[image]

Comment: "If I remove data" --- if by saying this you mean that you're assigning an empty string, why don't you assign `NULL` explicitly then?

Comment: I'm not explicitly assigning anything, TOAD is. I'm editing data in the grid. I remove data by clicking in a cell and removing it (backspace, delete key, select then cut, whatever). By doing that I want the cell to become `NULL` but instead TOAD makes it an empty string. So I have to keep running updates to set it to `NULL`.  Coming from an Oracle shop, this is very annoying.

Comment: What if instead of changing it to an empty string you just right click and see if there is something like "set to null" is available there. I don't have experience with TOAD Mysql explicitly, but I've seen it in another DB managers for mysql/postgresql.

Comment: If my answer is what you are looking for, could you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Control+Delete while selecting a cell

Comment: Thanks.  Can't believe I didn't try that :)

Comment: FYI, I just updated to version 7.2.0.2922 and you solution still works for it.